# MySQL - query optimisation: subquery, user-defined variables and join

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I am currently building a single (but extremely important in its context) query, which seems like it is working (qualitatively ok), but which I think/hope/wish could run faster.

I am running tests on MySQL 5.7.29, until a box running OmnisciDB in GPU mode can become available (which should be relatively soon). While I am hoping the switch to that different DB backend will improve performance, I am also aware it might require some tweaking in the table structures, querying techniques used, etc. But that is for later.

A little context:

**Data**
Is summed up as an extremely simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE `entities_for_perception` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `pos` POINT NOT NULL,
    `perception` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `stealth` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    SPATIAL INDEX `pos` (`pos`),
    INDEX `perception` (`perception`),
    INDEX `stealth` (`stealth`)
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_bin'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=10001
;
```

Which then contains values like (obvious but helps visualise :-) ):

```
| id | pos | perception | stealth |
|  1 | ... | 10         | 3       |
|  2 | ... | 6          | 5       |
|  3 | ... | 5          | 5       |
|  4 | ... | 7          | 7       |
etc..
```

Now I have this query (see below) whose intent is the following: **in one pass, fetch all the ids of the "entities" that see other entities and return the list of "who sees who"**.
[The "in one pass" is obvious and is to limit roundtrips.]
Let's assume POINT() is in a cartesian system.

The query is the following:

```
SHOW WARNINGS;
SET @automatic_perception_distance := 10;

SELECT
    *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        e1.id AS oid,
        e1.perception AS operception,
        @max_perception_distance := e1.perception * 5 AS 'max_perception_distance',
        @dist := ST_DISTANCE(e1.pos, e2.pos) AS 'dist',
        # minimum 0
        @dist_from_auto := GREATEST(@dist - @automatic_perception_distance, 0) AS 'dist_from_auto',
        @effective_perception := (
            @origin_perception - (
                @dist_from_auto
                / (@max_perception_distance - @automatic_perception_distance)
                * @origin_perception
            )
        ) AS 'effective_perception',
        e2.id AS tid,
        e2.stealth AS tstealth
    FROM 
        entities_for_perception e1
    INNER JOIN entities_for_perception e2 ON 
        e1.id != e2.id
    ORDER BY
        oid,
        dist
) AS subquery
WHERE 
    effective_perception >= tstealth
;
```

What it does is list "who seems whom" by applying the following criteria/filters:

1. determining a maximum distance beyond which perception is not possible
2. determining a minimal distance below which perception is automatic (not implemented yet)
3. determining an effective perception value varying (and regressing) with distance
4. ...and comparing the effective perception of the "spotter" versus the stealth of the "target".

This works, but runs somewhat slowly (laptop + virtualbox + centos7) on a table with very few rows (~1,000). The query time seems to fluctuate between 0.2 and 0.29 seconds. This is however orders of magnitude faster than it would be with one query per "spotter", which would not scale with 1,000+ spotters. Heh. :-)

Example of output:

```
| oid | operception | max_perception_distance | dist               | dist_fromt_auto    | effective_perception | tid | tstleath |
| 1   | 9           | 45                      | 1.4142135623730951 | 0                  | 9                    | 156 | 5        |
| 1   | 9           | 45                      | 11.045361017187261 | 1.0453610171872612 | 8.731192881294705    | 164 | 2        |
| 1   | 9           | 45                      | 13.341664064126334 | 3.341664064126334  | 8.140714954938943    | 163 | 8        |
| 1   | 9           | 45                      | 16.97056274847714  | 6.970562748477139  | 7.207569578963021    | 125 | 7        |
| 1   | 9           | 45                      | 25.019992006393608 | 15.019992006393608 | 5.137716341213072    | 152 | 3        |
| 1   | 9           | 45                      | 25.079872407968907 | 15.079872407968907 | 5.122318523665138    | 191 | 5        |
etc.
```

Could the reason for what I believe is a slow response:

1. be the subquery?
2. be the variables or the arithmetics applied to them?
3. the join?
4. something else I am not aware of?

Thank you for any insight!

Comment: Is an upgrade to MySQL 8 out of the question? A Common Table Expression might help.

Comment: Well one obvious optimisation would be to put the WHERE clause within the sub query, and thereby omit the super query altogether

Comment: @LarsSkaug nope not at all excluded, will try a quick install of 8.x and see what gives :-)

Comment: @Strawberry yes but I read on SO (somewhere.. cant remember that Mysql has a problem with row-level variables on a join. Please do take my word for it, though I a not able to dig up to very informative answer that was :)

Answer (score 0):

An index would probably help: `CREATE INDEX idx_ID ON entities_for_perception (id);`

If you were to upgrade to MySQL version 8, you could take advantage of a Common Table Expression as follows:

```
with e1 as (
    SELECT 
        e1.id AS oid,
        e1.perception AS operception,
        @max_perception_distance := e1.perception * 5 AS 'max_perception_distance',
        @dist := ST_DISTANCE(e1.pos, e2.pos) AS 'dist',
        # minimum 0
        @dist_from_auto := GREATEST(@dist - @automatic_perception_distance, 0) AS 'dist_from_auto',
        @effective_perception := (
            @origin_perception - (
                @dist_from_auto
                / (@max_perception_distance - @automatic_perception_distance)
                * @origin_perception
            )
        ) AS 'effective_perception',
        e2.id AS tid,
        e2.stealth AS tstealth
    FROM 
        entities_for_perception)
SELECT *
FROM  e1
    INNER JOIN entities_for_perception e2 ON 
        e1.id != e2.id
    ORDER BY
        oid,
        dist
WHERE 
    effective_perception >= tstealth
;
```